# Exception 'in' filters support a maximum of 10 elements in the value [List]

Tags: flutter, dart

### This error occurs when the page is visited 10 times

'in' filters support a maximum of 10 elements in the value [List].

'package:cloud_firestore/src/query.dart':

query.dart:1

Failed assertion: line 706 pos 11: '(value as List).length <= 10'

**This is the filter**

```
 final userProvider = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context);
    List filter = [];

    if (userProvider.isLoggedIn) {
      final model.User user = userProvider.getUser;

      user.following.add(user.uid);
      filter = user.following;
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
    }
```

The error occurs when the filter is activated

**Called in StreamBuilder**

```
 stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection('posts')
                  .where('uid', whereIn: filter)
                  .snapshots(),
              builder: (context,
                  AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }
```

error screen

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kdgN.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSeDr.png)

I hope someone can help me activate the filter because it caused this error

that is all my code

```
class FeedScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const FeedScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FeedScreen> createState() => _FeedScreenState();
}

class _FeedScreenState extends State<FeedScreen> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  bool isLoading = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    setStatus("Online");
    isLoading = true;
  }

  Future<void> setStatus(String status) async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
        .update({
      "status": status,
    });
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      // online
      setStatus("Online");
    } else {
      // offline
      setStatus("Offline");
    }
  }

//end user onlin or offline
  bool isSeemess = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    var refreshed;
    /////filter///////

    final userProvider = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context);
    List filter = [];

    if (userProvider.isLoggedIn) {
      final model.User user = userProvider.getUser;

      user.following.add(user.uid);
      filter = user.following;
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
    }

    // Provider.of<MessagesProvider>(context).messagesDatabase.get();

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor:
          width > webScreenSize ? webBackgroundColor : mobileBackgroundColor,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: appbarColor,
        centerTitle: false,
        title: SvgPicture.asset(
          'assets/logo.svg',
          color: primaryColor,
          height: 32,
        ),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.whatshot,
              color: primaryColor,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              //   Navigator.push(context, const AddPostScreen() );
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => Scaffold(
                    appBar: AppBar(
                      backgroundColor: appbarColor,
                      title: Text(
                        'uplode yor post'.tr,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                            color: primaryColor, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ),
                    body: const AddPostScreen(),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.search_outlined,
              color: primaryColor,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => const SearchScreen(),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
          //  FutureBuilder<List<MessageModel>>(
          //     future: Provider.of<MessagesProvider>(context).allMessages(),
          //     initialData: [],
          //     builder: (ctx, messages) {
          //     filtredMessages = allMessages
          //        .where((element) => element.friendName
          //             .toString()
          //         .toLowerCase()
          //         .contains(text.toLowerCase()))
          //     .toList();
          //  }),
          isSeemess
              ? IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.messenger_outline,
                    color: primaryColor,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => ChatHomeScreen(
                          uid: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid,
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                )
              : IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.messenger_outlined,
                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 235, 5, 185),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => ChatHomeScreen(
                          uid: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid,
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
          // IconButton(
          //   icon: const Icon(
          //     Icons.notification_important,
          //     color: primaryColor,
          //   ),
          //   onPressed: () {},
          // ),
        ],
      ),
      body: isLoading
          ? const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            )
          : StreamBuilder(
              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection('posts')
                  .where('uid', whereIn: filter)
                  .snapshots(),
              builder: (context,
                  AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }
                return ListView.separated(
                  reverse: true,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                  itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                  separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return const Divider();
                  },
                  itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: width > webScreenSize ? width * 0.3 : 0,
                      vertical: width > webScreenSize ? 15 : 0,
                    ),
                    child: PostCard(
                      snap: snapshot.data!.docs[index].data(),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

I just want to make a filter if you are a following or not, because it is not possible to download all the data, and only the followers’ posts must be shown, not all users

Comment: Every time your widget is built and `userProvider.isLoggedIn` is true, you're appending to the list `user.following.add(user.uid)` and using that as your filter. You'll need another way to track the information you want, remove duplicates (or prevent them from being added in the first place), etc. It's not really clear to me what this is trying to do so I'm unable to offer more specific suggestions.

Comment: I just want to make a filter if you are a following or not, because it is not possible to download all the data, and only the followers’ posts must be shown, not all users